# sed not terminating at the end of this line (issue with escaping?)

Tags: regex, sed

The SQL applications that I'm using isn't properly escaping all of the strings that I have, so I'm trying to use sed to replace these instances. The issue is I'll have this:

```
`some string of characters that may include hyphens'
and the quote at the end won't get escaped (yes that's supposed to be a ` not a quote).
```

My plan was to use this:

```
sed 's/[^\\]\'[^,]/&\\\'&/g' testfile.txt
```

Logic: anything that isn't a backslash followed by a quote, then anything that isn't a comma will be replaced by the same text with with a backslash and a quote.

I would like for testfile.txt to have all instances of ' replaced with \', but I just keep getting > as if it isn't done the line

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) points out that you [can't escape single quotes](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1003) with backslashes, and that you should use `'\''` instead of just `\'`. Can you fix that and try again?

Comment: By 'quotes' you mean backticks ```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this using gnu sed,

```
$ cat d
already escaped quote \' won't be escaped

$ sed -E "s/([^\\]|^)'([^,]|$)/\1\\\'\2/" d
already escaped quote \' won\'t be escaped
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are called lookaround assertions, where you match any `'` not preceded by a `\` or followed by an end of line. Unfortunately, sed doesn't support these. But you can use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)'\''(?!$)/\\'\''/g' testfile.txt
```

In unescaped form, this would look like `s/(?<!\\)'(?!$)/\\'/g` but we have to make allowances for the shell. No escapes are recognized in single quoted strings, so your original problem was `\'` not being recognized, and the string terminating early.

See here for example and detailed regexp breakdown: https://regex101.com/r/k8sonu/1